# RecyclerView Adapter Null Parameter in constructor

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

may I get an explain as to why one of the parameters i'm passing to my `RecyclerViewAdapter` is null when I try to access it in the `Adapter`? I've been looking at the fragments lifecycle but I cant seem to wrap my head around what's causing it to be null. 
In `onCreateView()` I have:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();;
        mUsersListView = view.findViewById(R.id.users_list);
        usersList = new ArrayList<>();
        usersRecyclerAdapter = new UsersRecyclerAdapter(container.getContext(), usersList, me);
        mUsersListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mUsersListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));
        mUsersListView.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);

        return view;
    }
```

And in `onStart()`:

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        usersList.clear();
        mFirestore.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), (documentSnapshots, e) -> {
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    String user_id = documentChange.getDocument().getId();
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().matches(user_id)) {
                        me = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);
                        System.out.println(me.getName()); //prints out a name
                        usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Users users = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId(user_id);
                        usersList.add(users);
                        usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My Adapter class looks like this

```
public class UsersRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Users> usersList;
    private Context context;
    private Users me;

    public UsersRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Users> usersList, Users me) {
        this.usersList = usersList;
        this.context = context;
        this.me = me;
        System.out.println(me.getName()); //this outputs null
    }

        @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      //
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {    
        //
    }

}
```

I want to keep a reference of the `me` object and pass it on to my adapter. However, when I try to access it there, it triggers a `NullPointerException`. The List is fine and can be accessed though. How come?

Comment: Have you instantiated `me` before passing it to adapter?

Comment: @MohamedHamza yes I did. Where I declared it. Users me = new Users(); However, calling the accessors in the adapter, return null. If I call the accessors in the fragment where I set documentChange to  "me", they give me actual data though.

Comment: Maybe something wrong in my Adapter? Should I post that?

Comment: So try to make a new method in adapter, with a Users variable as a parameter, something like updateMe(Users me){ this.me = me; }, and after getting me on fragment, call that method: adapter.updateme(me).. pardon mobile typing

Comment: Perfect. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks @MohamedHamza its working now

Comment: I'm glad. I making an answer, accept it and I will till you a nice little bonus 

Comment: We don't do SOLVED here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after discussing in comments, what helped was making a method to update `me` variable in the adapter:

`updateMe(Users me){ this.me = me; }`

And calling it from fragment whenever `me` changes.